# How to create multiple files with different names and in different folders? php

Tags: php

So, I have a .txt file with paths of my missing files. I want to write a little php script, that will just create those files and leave them blank.

```
xxx/yyy/xyxy/a/w/r/obvestilo.pdf
xxx/yyy/xyxy/b/print.pdf
xxx/yyy/xyxy/c/speach.doc
```

This is an example of how I have things in my .txt file of missing files. I would like the script to create me those files and also folders if they don't yet exist, but I have no clue where to begin. I was thinking to transfer that .txt file to an Array and then loop throug all array elements creating them.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: @gontrollez am trying right now, with no success... I can't seem to put txt file into array...

Comment: I think what I have should help you with a bit of tweaks if necessary. Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$fp = fopen('files.txt','r');
while(($buffer = fgets($fp,4096)) !== false) {
    $directory = substr($buffer,0,strrpos($buffer,'/') + 1);
    mkdir($directory, 0755, true);
    touch(trim($buffer));
}
```

`files.txt` will have your files in the format you have in your post.

The `mkdir($directory, 0755, true);` will create the required directory recursively and the `touch` will create a blank file.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
$data = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file_list.txt'));
foreach($data as $filename) {
  if(!file_exists(trim($filename))) {
    file_put_contents(trim($filename), '');
  }
}
```

That will write an empty string to each file in the list that doesn't already exist so you will get empty files. It won't create directories for you though, if you want to do that you'll need to do something a bit more complicated...

Comment: tnx, it rly helped.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the paths in your .txt file are absolute paths. If not than you will have to append some sort of `ROOT_DIRECTORY` constant in front of the paths.

Generally you would want to put this functionality in a class whose sole responsibility is to create these empty files:

```
class EmptyFileCreater {
    const USE_RECUSRION = true;
    const DEFAULT_ACCESS = 0777;

    public function create($path) {
        $this->ensureDirectoryExists(dirname($path));
        $this->createEmptyFile($path);            
    }

    private function ensureDirectoryExists($directory) {
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            mkdir($directory, self::DEFAULT_ACCESS, self::USE_RECUSRION);
        }
    }

    private function createEmptyFile($path) {
        touch($path);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this class to generate all the files.

```
// Retrieve the .txt file as an array of the lines in the file
$paths = file('path/to/missing_file_paths.txt');

$empty_file_creater = new EmptyFileCreater();
foreach ($paths as $path) {
    $empty_file_creater->create($path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
<?php 
$lines = file('test.txt'); ///path to your file
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{
    $fp = fopen($line,"wb");
    fwrite($fp,'');
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: useful, but I did it in a different way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method to create random names of specific lengths.

```
/*
     *
     * Get Random number( 5 digit )
     * @param int: 5
     * @return alphnumeric string: length(5)
     */

    public function getRandomNumber($length, $charset = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrpdctvwxyz3456789') {
        $str = '';
        $count = strlen($charset);
        while ($length--) {
            $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count - 1)];
        }
        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: The question states that there is a .txt file that already contains the exact directory path and filename, so I do not see any use for this method.